# How can I remove data from the page and it doesn't show?

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-state

I am trying to show the new data in my component when I delete it, so what I want to do is that when I delete that data it will no longer show on the page but when i click the button i have a error "cart.map is not a function", i need your help to show me how can i show new data in my page and to fix the error.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response=>{
        setCart(
            response.data
        );
    })
    .catch(e =>{
        console.log(e);
    })
}, [url])



 const handleDeleteItems = async(key, cart_id) =>{
   var yes = confirm("You are going to remove an item from your cart, are you sure you want to delete item?")

       if(yes===true){
       alert("succefull");
       const temp = [...cart];
       temp.splice(cart_id, 1);
       setCart({
           cart:temp
       });
   }}
```

This is my table where i show the data but it give me a error when i click the button

```
return (
   <div>
       <Table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
                   <th>Action</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           {cart.map((cart, key)=>{
               return(
                <tr key={cart.id}>
                <td>{cart.name}</td>
                <td>{cart.price}</td>
                <td>
                    <Button onClick={() => handleDeleteItems(key, cart.id)} variant="danger">Delete</Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
           )})}

           </tbody>
       </Table>
   </div>
```

Comment: You call `setCart({cart: temp})`, implying that `cart` is an object, but the spread `temp = [...cart]` suggests it is in fact an array. Show what the `cart` state actually looks like. The call `splice(card_id, 1)` also looks questionable - wouldn't you rather use the index (or `key` as you have named it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should add a validation to not try loading the cart data if it is empty or not initialized. In this example, we would show "No products yet" if the cart is empty.

```
{cart ? cart.map((cart, key)=>{
               return(
                <tr key={cart.id}>
                <td>{cart.name}</td>
                <td>{cart.price}</td>
                <td>
                    <Button onClick={() => handleDeleteItems(key, cart.id)} variant="danger">Delete</Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
           )}) : <>                     <td>No products yet.</td> 
</>}
```

Comment: After this, test your app and let's see the nexts steps.

Comment: i got it bro, thanks for you comment, i add a validation.